# go.Universe$proxyerror: invalid transaction v, r, s values

Tags: go-ethereum, android

I am getting this crash:

```
go.Universe$proxyerror: invalid transaction v, r, s values
    at org.ethereum.geth.EthereumClient.getBlockByNumber(Native Method)
```

for this call:

```
ethClient.getBlockByNumber(App.ethereumContext, -1).number
```

This happens with

```
compile  group: "org.ethereum", name: "geth", version: "1.5.7-SNAPSHOT"
```

unfortunately not always and I did not yet find a way to reproduce it - but perhaps somebody else already stumbled upon this and has some pointer on what the problem is here. I am just syncing / reading chaindata there currently - I do not change state there at all ( so no transaction or contract deployment when this happens).

Update: also happens with 1.5.8-SNAPSHOT